# Can not find css directory in header

Tags: css

I am beginner in wordpress. I am trying to give path of my css file in header.php and am I trying this, but I can not link my css file in my header.php

Is there any problem in my code. I can not find my css file in page source.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="jquery-ui-theme-css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/jquery-ui_002.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, try this in your functions.php

```
// Proper way to enqueue styles (from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
function wpse182193_load_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'my-stylesheet', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui_002.css', array(), '');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-stylesheet' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse182193_load_style' );
```

Comment: after that i have to include function file in my header.php or not..

Comment: If your theme has a functions.php you don't have to include anything more.

Comment: no it is not have that file so what me do now. me create that file in to my theme folder name is "function.php" and me put this function in this file..

Comment: I have no idea how a theme functions without functions.php so I really can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: it's ok i am trying to convert html in to wordpress so that is why i don not have that file in wordpress.. thank you @jimihenrik

Comment: @jimihenrik good answer. Just [edit] and mention that it will work when there would be `wp_head()` in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Alright then, I really don't see anything really wrong with your code, as long as you have your css file in http://`yourdomain.com`/wp-content/themes/`yourtheme`/css/jquery-ui_002.css

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` refers to your theme folder.

Comment: it's working local so i have to give path from my theme folder @MayeenulIslam

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam fair point, I think I'll just leave it as is for now as the thread derailed anyway, but I'll be sure to do that in the future, thanks. Now to sleep ->